# Load words in lines from file to sqlite table

Tags: c#, sqlite

I made function in c# to read line by line and then load lines to sqlite (s3db).

```
private void LoadFromDictionary()
    {
        Encoding enc = Encoding.GetEncoding(1250);
        using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader("c:\\Temp2\\dictionary.txt", enc))
        {
            string line = "";
            while ((line = r.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                line = line.Trim();
                AddWord(line);
            }
        }
        MessageBox.Show("Finally :P", "Info");
    }

    private void AddWord(string w)
    {
        String insSQL = "insert into Words values(\"" + w + "\")";
        String strConn = @"Data Source=C:\Temp2\dictionary.s3db";
        SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection(strConn);
        SQLiteDataAdapter da = new SQLiteDataAdapter(insSQL, strConn);
        da.Fill(dt);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt.DefaultView;
    }
```

But is it any faster way? I created table by sqlite administrator application.
Can sqlite load itself file and make it as a table?

---

I am talking about 3+ millions words (one word in one line).

PS. please correct my topic if there is something wrong :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is a much, much faster method using the following techniques:

1) Only open a connection to the database one time

2) Use a parameterized command for better performance and lower overhead (don't have to use new strings on each pass).

3) Wrap the entire operation in a transaction. As a general rule, this will improve your performance.

Note that I do not show transaction rollback or closing the connection, which are also best practices that should be implemented.

```
private void LoadFromDictionary()
    {
            Encoding enc = Encoding.GetEncoding(1250);
            string strConn = @"Data Source=C:\Temp2\dictionary.s3db";
            SqliteConnection conn = new SqliteConnection(strConn);

            conn.Open();

            string insSQL = "insert or ignore into wyrazy values(@Word)";

            DbCommand oCommand = conn.CreateCommand();

            oCommand.Connection = conn;
            oCommand.CommandText = insSQL;

            DbParameter oParameter = oCommand.CreateParameter();
            oParameter.Name = "@Word";
            oParameter.DbType = DbType.String;
            oParameter.Size = 100;

            oCommand.Parameters.Add(oParameter);

            DbTransaction oTransaction = conn.BeginTransaction();

            using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader("c:\\Temp2\\dictionary.txt", enc))
            {
                string line = "";
                while ((line = r.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    line = line.Trim();
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(line)) {
                      oParameter.Value = line;
                      oCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                }
            }
            oTransaction.Commit();

            conn.Close();

            MessageBox.Show("Finally :P", "Info");
        }
```

Comment: Hmm I have problem with `DbTransaction oTransaction = conn.BeginTransaction();` `Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.`

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add opening the connection. Modified the code (also added close for completeness).

Comment: Could you explain me how does it work? In my table "Words" in sqlite I wrote `CREATE TABLE [Words] ( [word] VARCHAR(100) UNIQUE NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY )` I am not able input words `Abort due to constraint violation column wyraz is not unique` what should I do?

Comment: It sounds like you have repeating words in the file or the table. If you have run the app more than once without clearing the table, then you will have this problem. Your insert statement to INSERT OR IGNORE (see http://www.sqlite.org/lang_conflict.html for details).

Comment: First word from file is `aa` and the second is `aaa`. The file contains only unique words.

Comment: Just change string **insSQL = "insert into** to **string insSQL = "insert or ignore into**

Comment: I am sure there is problem with that `@Word`

Comment: Yes that `@Word` with quotes :P was the problem :D Just remove them :)

Comment: Did the last change I made fix it? I changed the @Word to ? I also added a check to make sure there was something in the line before writing it.

Comment: I have just replaced `"insert into Words values('@Word')"` to `"insert into Words values(@Word)"`. I have removed that single quotes around `@Word` :) Because with quotes I was adding @Word as a word to table, every time.

Comment: Ok, I have updated the answer. Sounds like that should work then.

Comment: yeah :) you are the boss on that topic :)

Answer (score 0):

You could try [bulk insert](http://procbits.com/2009/09/08/sqlite-bulk-insert/). By reading this article please pay special attention to the parametrized queries being used there and which you should use instead of the string concatenations in your sample in the `insSQL` variable.

Answer (score 0):

Using Transactions usually speed things up quite a bit, depending on your desired batch size. I'm not 100% as familiar with DataAdapters and DataSources but instead of creating a new connection every time to insert one row, modify your code to use one connection and use SQLiteConnection.BeginTransaction() and the when you are done call Transaction.Commit().

Answer (score 0):

I just did this the other day, first use a transaction, and parameterized queries.  I was able to load 16 million rows in about a minute doing this.

```
internal static void FastInsertMany(DbConnection cnn)
{
  using (DbTransaction dbTrans = cnn.BeginTransaction())
  {
    using (DbCommand cmd = cnn.CreateCommand())
    {
      cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO TestCase(MyValue) VALUES(?)";

      DbParameter Field1 = cmd.CreateParameter();

      cmd.Parameters.Add(Field1);

      for (int n = 0; n < 100000; n++)
      {
        Field1.Value = n + 100000;
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
      }
    }

    dbTrans.Commit();

  }
}
```